# ld: library not found for -lssl / clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Tags: macos, ssl, linker-errors, paho

I am trying to build Paho client on my macOS Moneterey12.3.
When I run make command, I get the following errors

ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib'
ld: library not found for -lssl
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib doesn't exist on my device. How do I remove this option from compile? Also, I am not sure how to fix the -lssl problem.

Answer (score 0):

As described in the README for the project here:

https://github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.c#build-requirements--compilation-using-cmake

Use cmake to build the project, not the shipped `Makefile`.

```
git clone https://github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.c.git
cd paho.mqtt.c
mkdir build
cd build
cmake -DPAHO_WITH_SSL=FALSE ..
make
```